# How to download and install Emacs for OCaml?

Tags: emacs, installation, ocaml, tuareg

I feel retarded asking this question, but I've been banging my head against the wall for a while now...

This directory is linked to by the website for obtaining emacs: http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/. Which file do I want? I downloaded `emacs-23.1.tar.gz` and unpacked it, but I don't know what to do now. I can't find any files to execute.

(I'm running Vista.)

And then I want to use tuareg mode with OCaml. Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you've downloaded the source code, which probably isn't what you want. It might be easier for you to go to [download site](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/) and download the binaries.

Getting Tuareg to work is as easy as downloading it and following the [installation instructions](http://www-rocq.inria.fr/~acohen/tuareg/mode/). Some options that I like for Tuareg (but YMMV!):

```
(setq tuareg-default-indent 4)
(setq tuareg-with-indent 2)
(setq tuareg-|-extra-unindent 2)
```

Incidentally, set up and whatnot is much easier using Virtualbox + Linux VM;  if you're just wanting to play around with Ocaml/Emacs then it might be easier to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the linux version - you should instead download http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-23.1-bin-i386.zip

Once you have it, emacs can be started from bin/runemacs

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at EmacsW32 -- it is GNU Emacs with a few tweaks to make it more comfortable for Windows users: http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html